# onblur event distinguishes in IE/Firefox / Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

i'm using on HTML input fields the onblurevent to validate input directy after leaving the field. In the eventhandler look after the id of source element and call validation methods:

```
<input  id="ex1"  onblur="app.checkInput(event);" />
<input  id="ex2"  onblur="app.checkInput(event);" />
```

my JS-validation:

```
this.checkInput = function(event) {
    var result;
    if (event.srcElement.id == 'ex1') {
      result = this.validateEx1();
    }
    else if ( event.srcElement.id == 'ex2') {
      result = this.validateEx12();
    } //...
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome, but the event parameter has in Firefox no Field 'srcElement'. Is there a way to make it compatible for all browsers?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with standards.

You can use `target` or `currentTarget`

```
 event.currentTarget.id;
```

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget